# Unable to launch application after upgrade to Asp.net beta8

Tags: asp.net-core

Recently upgrading my application from ASP.NET beta7 to beta8 following these excellent instructions: http://wildermuth.com/2015/10/20/Upgrading_from_ASP_NET_5_Beta_7_to_Beta_8

Unfortunately I still cannot launch my application.  If I try to launch with Kestel (web) I get 500 Internal Server error before debug even hits my breakpoints in Startup.cs (it does still hit my breakpoints).  If I try to launch in IISExpress I get the following error:

```
 Could not load type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.EntryPoint' from assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

 [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.EntryPoint' from assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.]
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +303

 [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.EntryPoint' from assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.]
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9922864
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

I've looked everywhere and compared to other beta8 examples to no avail.  Why can't I launch the application anymore?  Here are my applicable files -

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "development"
      },
      "sdkVersion": "dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8"
    },
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

project.json

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler":  "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "StreakMaker.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "StreakMaker.Business": "1.0.0-*",
    "React.AspNet": "2.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR": "2.2.0",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Data.Linq": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install" ],
    "prepare": [ "gulp copy" ]
  },
  "configurations": {
    "development": { },
    "production": { },
    "staging": { }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal;
using Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Framework.Logging;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using StreakMaker.Business;
using StreakMaker.Data.Context;
using StreakMaker.Data.Model;
using StreakMaker.Data.Repositories;
using StreakMaker.Data.Repositories.Contracts;
using React.AspNet;

namespace StreakMaker
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            // Setup configuration sources.
            var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true);

            if (env.IsEnvironment("development"))
            {
                // This reads the configuration keys from the secret store.
                // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                configBuilder.AddUserSecrets();
            }
            configBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            _configuration = configBuilder.Build();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(_configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

            //using (ApplicationDbContext ctx = DbContextActivator.CreateInstance<ApplicationDbContext>(services.BuildServiceProvider()))
            //{
            //    ctx.Database.Migrate();
            //}

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddTransient<IMessageService, MessageService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddReact();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
        {
            loggerfactory.AddConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Warning);

            if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage(DatabaseErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            // For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = _configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                options.AppSecret = _configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
            });
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = _configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = _configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            });
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = _configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = _configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientSecret"];
            });
            app.UseTwitterAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.ConsumerKey = _configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerKey"];
                options.ConsumerSecret = _configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Dashboard" });

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "streak",
                    template: "{friendlyUrl}",
                    defaults: new {controller = "Streak", action = "Detail"});

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "defaultApi", 
                    template: "api/{controller}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseReact(config =>
            {
                config
                    .AddScript("~/scripts/Feed/LiveFeedForm.js")
                    .AddScript("~/scripts/Feed/LiveFeedRow.js")
                    .AddScript("~/scripts/Feed/LiveFeedList.js")
                    .AddScript("~/scripts/Common/TextInput.js");

                config.SetJsonSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which runtime is selected when you run dnvm list? I'm wondering if it is pointing to beta7 by accident? Also did you install the latest web tools along with the beta 8 installation?

Comment: Like @armen.shimoon said, take a look at your project's Properties and see if the correct DNX version is set up. Also, make sure you installed the latest version of DNVM and WebTools for Visual Studio.

Comment: I know I have updated dnvm to use beta8 and am pointed to beta8 in the project properties.  I'm also using .net 4.5.1 instead of core because not all of the libraries work with core (react.net, signalr).  I'm pretty sure I updated VS web tools but will check that when I can.

Comment: @RyanLangton Specifically you need WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi like shown here http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html

Comment: It was the WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi that I needed to install.  I am now able to run in IISExpress.  Kestrel still gives me the immediate error 500.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your project is configured to run as Beta8 (Project Properties) and that your `dnvm list` shows that you have beta8 installed.

Then, make sure that you don't have a `AspNetLoader.dll` anywhere in `wwwroot\bin`.

Ready?

`Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.EntryPoint` was the entrypoint for the Helios shim (AspNetLoader.dll) in-between ASP.NET 5 and IIS. Here's what you should do to make it work:

1. Ensure that `Startup.cs:Configure` method has the following line first:  `app.UseIISPlatformHandler()`
2. Make sure you don't have the following environment variable set: `WEBPROJ_ENABLEBETA7RENAMES`
3. Update `global.json` for latest runtime version.

That should get you going. Tell me if you have a different error message.

Here's my [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364#issuecomment-148567294).